# Confusion in derivation of bias variance decomposition

Tags: machine-learning, variance, data-mining

This question is regarding derivation of bias-variance decomposition as answered (which was accepted) in another [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189806/derivation-of-bias-variance-decomposition-expression-for-k-nearest-neighbor-regr). I am repeating the steps for this question:

\begin{align}  \newcommand{\var}{{\rm var}}
{\rm variance} &= \var \left( \frac{1}{k} \sum_i^k Y(x_i) \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2}  \sum_i^k \var \left( f(x_i) + \epsilon_i \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2}  \sum_i^k \var \left( f(x_i) \right) + \var \left( \epsilon_i \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2}  \sum_i^k \var \left( \epsilon_i \right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{k^2} k \sigma_\epsilon^2  \\
&= \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{k}
\end{align}

**Question 1:** How did the author get $$\frac{1}{k^2}$$ in the 2nd step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
var(aX)&=E \left[ (aX-E\right[ {aX}\left])^2\right]\\
&=E\left[ (aX-aE\right[X\left])^2\right]\\
&=E\left[ (a(X-E\right[X\left]))^2\right]\\
&=E\left[a^2(X-E\right[X\left])^2\right]\\
&=a^2E\left[ (X-E\right[X\left])^2\right]\\
&=a^2var(X)
\end{align}
This depends on $E(aX)=aE(X)$.